# Best way to travel from Bangalore to Chennai by road

Tags: india, road-trips, bangalore, chennai, south-india

I am planning to drive down from Bangalore to Chennai? Which is the best route to take? How much toll do I need to pay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options for you -

- Via Kolar & Chittor which is shorter by 30KMs but slower due to two lane roads and no toll.
- Via Krishnagiri & Vellore, quicker but one need to pay toll.

There are 5 toll booths between Bangalore and Chennai via Krishnagiri. Toll keeps varying as the toll operators keep changing the toll every 4-6 months.

Comment: "Toll keeps varying as the toll operators keep changing the toll every 4-6 months."... What does that mean??

Comment: @Fiksdal: Hope he is about the amount to pay the toll gates, the fare may revised on every 6 months. So he doesn't know the exact amount to pay for the tolls.It is his answer for the _How much toll do I need to pay?_